# how to create SDK in android

Tags: android, sdk

I want to create an SDK like Paypal. where after a specific point all work is done by SDK. like when we integrated Paypal SDK, then after a specific point all the rest of the process of payment is done by Paypal SDK. I also want to create something like this, that after calling my SDK code rest of the work I want to do by my SDK code. I searched for that, but unfortunately, I did not find proper guidance to achieve this. please guide someone on how can we do that. and sorry for my poor English.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's looks like you mislead with terminology. From your question it's more likely that you wanna create some library that will do a part of work for some common goal.

Here is some example:
https://medium.com/@anujguptawork/how-to-create-your-own-android-library-and-publish-it-750e0f7481bf